# How do I annotate vector length?

Tags: rust

I'd like to annotate a function parameter that contains a vector.

example:

```
fn test(mut myvector: Vec<u8>) -> Vec<u8>{
  if myvector.is_empty() {
      panic!("Your vector should have at least one element")
   }
  myvector[0] += 1u8; // this will also panic if vector is empty
  myvector
}
```

Instead of throwing an error if the vector is empty, is there anyway to tell the compiler that the vector should have 3 elements or maybe at least guarantee it's not empty?

Answer (score 5):

The Rust solution to this is to make a wrapper type that strictly requires at least one entry:

```rust
struct NonEmtpyVec(Vec<T>)

impl<T> Deref for NonEmptyVec<T> {
  type Target = Vec<T>;

  fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
    &self.0
  }
}
```

Where you test on construction, and prevent alterations that could result on a zero-length array. You could do this with a `TryFrom` conversion operator, or a `new()` that returns a `Result`.

This might be really heavy-handed, but it means that this function doesn't need to check, it's already good to go. It pushes the obligation up the chain closer to where the data is inserted.

I'd suggest you steer away from `panic!` except in situations where something has gone so horribly wrong you need to shut it all down immediately. It's usually far better to return a `Result` that needs to be handled or ignored at the caller's peril.